# Changing Branch in Git

Tags: git

I could not come back to the **master** branch. I used several [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) command. I am mentioning all those with the result below.

**git checkout master**

Output:

> error:pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

**git branch master**

Output:

> fatal: Not a valid object name : 'greet'.

**git branch**

**git branch -d greet**

Output:

> fatal:Couldn't look up commit object for HEAD

I searched a lot in Google Search and Stack Overflow, but I could not find any solution. I installed and reinstalled Git several times. Also, I have tried to delete all the folders related to Git to get a solution.

Comment: Which git command did you execute after installing git and before doing git checkout? Did you execute `git init` or `git clone`?

Comment: Just so you know, your first attempt is correct (`git checkout master`) - but there's something wrong with your repository.

Comment: Are you saying the `git branch` produced NO output at all? That indicates something is very wrong with the repository. Can you also add output of `git status`, please?

Comment: There must be a canonical question for this. Where is it?

Comment: Related: *[Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git checkout master` will do that if you haven't committed any files to it.

```
mkdir project ; cd $_ ; git init .
```

Output:

> Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/doon/Desktop/project/.git/

And:

```
git checkout master
```

Output:

> error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

If you've changed to another branch, `git checkout -b branchname`, you can switch back to *master* the same way, `git checkout -b master`. Once you stage and commit files, you will no longer get that error (assuming you stage/commit to the *master* branch).

Comment: Now I am in a new problem. I would like to push my local repository to github, I used following command and got result like below.

`$ git push origin master`

ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
And the repository exists.    

Can you say what is the solution ?? Where is the problem ??

Comment: @FoysalFoysal Probably best to ask that as a new question.